# How to save parsed data into sqlite database in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am new in iphone, i am developing an ipad application (like offline mode application) in which data are comes from server and i have parsed these data and store into nsmutable array, now i want to insert these data into sqlite database how to do please give me some sample code. Any one help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading this  http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/  tutorial its the easiest way to perform sqlite operations. you will just need to fire queries like SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](http://mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/)

It provides multiple tutorials on how to accomplish your goal.

*PS: In the future, type your Stack OVerflow question into Google first and see if that solves your problem. If not, post it.*